# How to populate a table using loop function in R?

Tags: r

I have a csv table with items numbers in column 1 ( column name: items) and variables in column 2 through 26 ( Columns title "B" -> "Z")

items   A       B    C      ...     Z
1     JUN2004       OCT2010 ....    MAR2005
2       SEP2012         DEC2009
3     APR2007           AUG2011

I need to create a new table where column title Year( " 2004",   "2005",  "2006",  "2007" ........ "2012")

The row should be contained row value like "A" , or "B" or "C" ..... or "Z"

what is the best way to do this?

My new table should look like

items      2004     2005     2006      ...     2012 
1           A                 C        ....     Z
2                    B                 .... 
3           A                                   Z

Answer (score 0):

We can `gather` into 'long' format, do the processing on the 'val' column and then `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(df1, key, val, -items) %>%
   mutate(val = str_remove(val, "\\D+")) %>%
   spread(val, key)
```